# C# - Assigning user input into a list in a for loop

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to assign user given names into name variables (Player1, Player2, etc).

The amount of players the program asks for is dependent on the amount the user gives (int TotalPlayers). So if the user says the total to be 5, then the for loop would ask for 5 names and not more.

Im trying to achieve this by first adding all user inputs into a list and then assigning the names in the list into Name Variables later but I can't seem to make this work.

Can someone help me fix the errors or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

```
Console.WriteLine("Write amount of players");
int TotalPlayers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

List<string> PlayerList = new List<string>();

for (int players = 0; players < TotalPlayers; players++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter player {0}'s name:", players + 1);
    PlayerList.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine(PlayerList);
```

Comment: What specific errors are you seeing?  Note that you likely want to do `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", PlayerList)` to actually get useful info.

Comment: You are writing out a list. Shouldn't you be looping through it?

Comment: Yep, for one thing you're just printing the name of the list object. Also, probably not the problem here, but it's annoying me that your program will crash if the user accidentally enters a non-numeric value for player count.... so maybe use something like this:  `int TotalPlayers;
            while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out TotalPlayers)){Console.WriteLine("Value must be numeric... Write amount of players");}`

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thanks guys!
@u8it, I've been meaning to figure out how to solve that error, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code above looks to be executing correctly but I think we need some more information. What does your name variable look like? if you wanted you can just create a list of those through the loop like so.

say NameVariable is some simple object.

```
public class NameVariable 
{ 
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then your code would look something like:

```
public static void Main()
{
      Console.WriteLine("Write amount of players");
            int TotalPlayers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            List<NameVariable> PlayerList = new List<NameVariable>();

            for (int index = 0; index < TotalPlayers; index++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter player {0}'s name:", index + 1);
                PlayerList.Add(new NameVariable(){
                    Name = Console.ReadLine(),
                    Id = index
                });
            }

    foreach(var player in PlayerList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(player.Name);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This made everything so much easier. My code was correct and it was doing what I needed it to do but what I wanted to do next just got improved a lot by using a class for the names.

Comment: The foreach loop at the end displays all the names in the NameVariable class, I'd to assign them to strings instead. Before I used string player1 = PlayerList[0]. But it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: hey Sulhan, if you are just looking to put all those names back into a list of strings you could keep the original List<string> and in the final loop add to it as you iterate through the PlayerList so just below the line "Console.WriteLine(player.Name);" you could write ListOfString.Add(player.Name) then you will have a list of strings also. hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's the `Console.WriteLine(PlayerList);` that is causing you problems.
This uses the built-in `ToString` method from the base object which will give you

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Or similar.

You can try `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", PlayerList));` to get a simple string list.

Most of the time, the default string generation in .Net is not what you want, and you will need to loop over your list and build the string yourself.

Comment: Seems right to me. I'd add that a good basic format might be something like this... `PlayerList.Insert(0, "\tAll Players Accepted"); Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n\t", PlayerList));`

Comment: Yeah, that first line of code was what i was getting what I had written in the code and I thought my code wasn't working properly. It has been corrected now. Thanks!